# How to delete the default bar in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently developing my first app in android studio and i am facing a problem that i tried to fix for a while now.
I am trying to remove the first action bar.
I tried changing the theme to a .noActionBar one but to result
Please check out the image for a visual explanation

[image]

this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.user.survay_1.SecondActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:background="#00a4f9"
    android:visibility="visible">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: can u add a theme in `manifest.xml` file like `.noactionbar`

Answer (score 2):

change your theme `NoActionBar` at styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

also add

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

declare custom theme in your style.xml file like this..

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
</style>
```

then in your manifest give your activity theme like this..

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityName"
           android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"> 
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

write below code in `Style.xml`:

```
<style name="LoginTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Now u call this theme in `manifest.xml` with adding this line `android:theme="@style/LoginTheme"`

See `manifest.xml` look like :

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:theme="@style/LoginTheme"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

> In your **Activity** just use this :- **only one line**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.
***First way*** is to disable it in **`styles.xml`** file:

### styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme.NoActionBar" parent="CustomTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And in your **`AndroidManifest.xml`** you can use it for all activities:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Or for one activity only:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.NoActionBar">
```

***The second way*** is to hide action bar from your activity:

### Activity.class

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
   getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```